Can't use ROS2 bridge with Gazebo LRAUV simulator
I was trying to control the LRAUV simulator using ROS2 and I ran into an issue where I fail to create a bridge to the horizontal and vertical fins.
Error:
[WARN] [1733322791.663024490] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/tethys/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with ROS2 type [std_msgs/msg/Float64] to topic [/model/tethys/joint/vertical_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with Gazebo Transport type [gz.msgs.Double]
[WARN] [1733322791.662512873] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/tethys/joint/horizontal_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with ROS2 type [std_msgs/msg/Float64] to topic [/model/tethys/joint/horizontal_fins_joint/0/cmd_pos] with Gazebo Transport type [gz.msgs.Double]
it works for the thruster but not the fins. Has anyone encountered this issue?
